# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, minecraft-forge

Im trying to append some things to a google sheet from a Custom GUI in Minecraft.
When i try the same code, isolatet, from IntelliJ instead of ingame it workes.
Ingame it throws this error:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer
```

Its thrown at the "<---" in the code below:

```
public AppendValuesResponse execute(String APPLICATION_NAME) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, MissingEntryException {
        Sheets sheetsService = SheetsAPI.getSheetsService(APPLICATION_NAME);
        if(SHEET_ID == null || RANGE == null ||INPUT == null)
            throw new MissingEntryException("One or more Values are null: SHEET_ID: '"+SHEET_ID+"', RANGE: '"+RANGE+"', SHEET_ID: '" + INPUT.toString() + "'");

        ValueRange appendBody = new ValueRange().setValues(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(INPUT)));

        Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.Append append = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values()
                .append(SHEET_ID, RANGE, appendBody)
                .setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED")
                .setInsertDataOption("OVERWRITE")
                .setIncludeValuesInResponse(true);

        return append.execute(); <---
    }
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Using Gradle, load the Dependency like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.42.2'
```

Comment: How exactly are you injecting this librabry? The error message says it basically. The class `com/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer` is not existing. So I guess the JAR of this dependency is not loaded correctly.

Comment: updated it for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the dependency `google-http-client`in your class path. If you use maven you can add:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
    <version>${version.google.http.client}</version>
</dependency>
```

where `version.google.http.client` is the version of the library which is compatible to the library that requires the class.

Comment: Ty, do u know which version that is? the first one you had didnt work :/